# Spherical capacitor properties

Tags: capacitor, conductors, electrostatic

If we consider a spherical capacitor (having an inner conducting ring surrounded by another such conducting ring), how can charge reside on the inner surface since it's surrounded by another conductor?

Further, how is it possible for potential difference to exist between the two surfaces since the **Electric field** inside a conductor must be zero in electrostatic condition?

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Please draw a picture describing the capacitor and depicting (unusually) a conducting ring inside a spherical component. How can an inner ring be surrounded by another inner ring? Do you mean coaxial rings separated by a gap... draw a picture.

Comment: @Andyaka sure, i have attached a picture from the book where i found this topic

Comment: When asking a question of a community of volunteers, it would go a long way for you to learn how to crop and rotate photos for the benefit of your audience.

Comment: @JYelton thank you, i would keep this in mind whenever i post something next

Answer (score 2):

> *how is it possible for potential difference to exist between the two
> surfaces since the Electric field inside a conductor must be zero in
> electrostatic condition?*

The electric field inside an ideal conductor is indeed zero. However, that is irrelevant because, if the inner and outer spheres are unconnected, an electric field can exist between them.

Here's an example of a battery inside the two spheres forming an electric field: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> how can charge reside on the inner surface since its surrounded by another conductor?

Consider the following scenario. There is a spherical conductor with charge on it. One then takes two larger hemispheres, and attaches them together outside of the first sphere. Would the charge on the inner sphere disappear? Or would it still be there? (A more likely scenario, is that there is a hole in the outer sphere with a wire going through it to the inner sphere, but that might raise questions, hence my thought experiment.

> how is it possible for potential difference to exist between the two surfaces since the Electric field inside a conductor must be zero in electrostatic condition?

You have overgeneralized. There field within outer conductive sphere must be zero *IF* there is no charge trapped within the sphere. That is not the case here.